# AndroidJavaException: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException

Tags: java, android, unity3d

у меня появляется ошибка

```
2021-07-15 20:59:14.583 1050-10832/? E/AwareLog: KeyThreadRecognize: dir null
2021-07-15 20:59:14.583 1050-10832/? E/AwareLog: KeyThreadRecognize: get sortedStat error
2021-07-15 20:59:14.702 1674-2156/? E/AwareLog: AwareMem_MemoryUtils: trim Memory illegal arg exception, proc:7672 userId:-2 level:40 fromAware:true
2021-07-15 20:59:14.825 1674-2915/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: failed to find this proc.
2021-07-15 20:59:14.833 8058-8058/? E/n.up.casino.vl: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-15 20:59:14.856 8058-8077/? E/BehaviorCollectManager: Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...
2021-07-15 20:59:14.962 2943-21132/? E/DollieActivityManagerAdapter: HwActivityNotifierEx null uid
2021-07-15 20:59:14.974 2752-2752/? E/RtgSchedManager: endActivityTransaction: margin state not match
2021-07-15 20:59:14.978 1674-15404/? E/ZrHung.AppEyeFocusWindow: NFW check!
2021-07-15 20:59:14.982 2752-2752/? E/RtgSchedManager: endActivityTransaction: margin state not match
2021-07-15 20:59:14.985 2891-3829/? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:bta_gattc_act.cc(238)] bta_gattc_deregister p_clreg->num_clcb is 0
2021-07-15 20:59:14.990 1073-1295/? E/ScreemCommon: <LOGMGR> <CountFlowErrBigData> [monitors[0] is null.]
2021-07-15 20:59:14.991 2675-2831/? E/AwareLog: SPKVolumeSchedFeature: Uid has been sent, ignore.
2021-07-15 20:59:14.991 1674-1835/? E/WindowManager: icon is null!!
2021-07-15 20:59:14.995 8058-8086/? E/AppLovinSdk: [DataCollector] Could not collect Google Advertising ID - this will negatively impact your eCPMs! Please integrate the Google Play Services SDK into your application. More info can be found online at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. If you're sure you've integrated the SDK and are still seeing this message, you may need to add a ProGuard exception: -keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { public protected *; }
    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:88)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source:47)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.m.c(Unknown Source:15)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.m.b(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.m$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
2021-07-15 20:59:14.996 8058-8088/? E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@687290e
2021-07-15 20:59:15.010 1674-2156/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: proc should not less than zero.
2021-07-15 20:59:15.024 2675-2921/? E/AwareLog: KeyThreadRecognize: can not find max eas level for: com.pin.up.casino.vlk
2021-07-15 20:59:15.025 2675-2921/? E/AwareLog: AwareGameFreq: gameFreqGov is invalid.
2021-07-15 20:59:15.057 8058-8058/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
2021-07-15 20:59:15.110 1674-2156/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: proc should not less than zero.
2021-07-15 20:59:15.111 1674-16733/? E/WindowManager: App trying to use insecure INPUT_FEATURE_NO_INPUT_CHANNEL flag. Ignoring
2021-07-15 20:59:15.121 2943-3074/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.pin.up.casino.vlk/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10971
2021-07-15 20:59:15.127 1674-16733/? E/ZrHung.AppEyeFocusWindow: cancel check
2021-07-15 20:59:15.127 998-1516/? E/DE N ABT: mergeProcessorOperatingNormal:1519: COMPONENT_GMP already has data, can't add new data with MODE_COLOR_ENHANCE, mode:MODE_GAME|MODE_COLOR_ENHANCE|0x900->MODE_GAME|MODE_COLOR_ENHANCE|0x900
2021-07-15 20:59:15.127 998-1516/? E/DE N ABT: mergeProcessorOperatingNormal:1519: COMPONENT_GMP already has data, can't add new data with MODE_COLOR_ENHANCE, mode:MODE_GAME|MODE_COLOR_ENHANCE|0x900->MODE_GAME|MODE_COLOR_ENHANCE|0x900
2021-07-15 20:59:15.128 1674-2156/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: proc should not less than zero.
2021-07-15 20:59:15.129 2943-3074/? E/SmartDualCardConfig: isAppInBlackList false,items==null
2021-07-15 20:59:15.130 2943-3074/? E/ScgQuickAddManager: the compName is :com.pin.up.casino.vlk
2021-07-15 20:59:15.281 1674-1835/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{eb03bfc u0 Splash Screen com.pin.up.casino.vlk EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
2021-07-15 20:59:15.310 1037-3834/? E/Thermal-daemon:ambient: CalcAmbientTemp: median filter output 27476
2021-07-15 20:59:15.310 1037-3834/? E/Thermal-daemon:ambient: AmbientSample: write temp 27476 to ambient node
2021-07-15 20:59:15.332 747-2255/? E/AudioPolicyIntefaceImpl: selectDevice() IDeviceSelectCallback == nullptr
2021-07-15 20:59:15.363 1059-1059/? E/Sensors@1.2-impl: Sensors::batch: sensorHandle: 0, samplingPeriodNs: 200000000, maxReportLatencyNs: 0
2021-07-15 20:59:15.364 1059-1059/? E/Sensors@1.2-impl: Sensors::batch: sensorHandle: 0, samplingPeriodNs: 20000000, maxReportLatencyNs: 0
2021-07-15 20:59:15.428 2943-3074/? E/DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher state:6 fg:false mUid:10067
2021-07-15 20:59:15.431 2943-3074/? E/SmartDualCardConfig: isAppInBlackList false,items==null
2021-07-15 20:59:15.431 2943-3074/? E/ScgQuickAddManager: uidInfo.isForeGroundUid() is false
2021-07-15 20:59:15.461 1674-2122/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{f7145d u0 com.huawei.intelligent.Workspace} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false
2021-07-15 20:59:15.461 1674-2122/? E/WindowManager: win=Window{831448c u0 com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher} destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false win.mRemoveOnExit=false
2021-07-15 20:59:15.658 3196-3478/? E/DeviceMonitorPowerKit: not Satify ApplyResource
2021-07-15 20:59:15.760 752-752/? E/FrameEvents: addLatch: Did not find frame.
2021-07-15 20:59:16.276 488-488/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for interface=vendor.huawei.hardware.sensors::ISensors sid=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c203,c259,c512,c768 pid=8058 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c203,c259,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:default_hisi_hwservice:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=0
2021-07-15 20:59:16.278 1059-1059/? E/Sensors@1.2-impl: Sensors::batch: sensorHandle: 0, samplingPeriodNs: 10000000, maxReportLatencyNs: 0
2021-07-15 20:59:17.590 1674-2915/? E/ProcessInfoCollector: getProcessInfo: failed to find this proc.
2021-07-15 20:59:17.596 8270-8270/? E/ocessService0:: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2021-07-15 20:59:17.617 8270-8303/? E/ActivityThread: getApplicationInfo metadata error
2021-07-15 20:59:17.618 8270-8303/? E/BehaviorCollectManager: Fail to acquire dataAnalyzerService...
2021-07-15 20:59:17.620 8058-8305/? E/Appodeal:  
    
    ATTENTION:
        Adapters are not registered in you app: 
            NAST, MRAID, VAST.
        Please add the dependencies for them to improve your fill rates and increase revenue.
        If you are sure that you do not need these adapters, skip this warning.
     
2021-07-15 20:59:18.444 9675-9675/? E/HiBoard_21.0.25.331_LauncherOverlayService: onUnbind
2021-07-15 20:59:19.067 8058-8141/? E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
    com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:88)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source:47)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source:95)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:20)
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CheckException () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
      at UnityEngine.AndroidJNISafe.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr clazz, System.IntPtr methodID, UnityEngine.jvalue[] args) 
2021-07-15 20:59:22.607 3196-10480/? E/nearby: NearbyPowerKit:not Satify ApplyResource
```

вот список моих зависимостей

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

// Android Resolver Repos Start
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/artifactory/appodeal" // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AdColonyDependencies.xml:11, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AmazonAdsDependencies.xml:9, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppLovinDependencies.xml:11, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:18, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:46, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/FacebookAudienceDependencies.xml:12, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/IronSourceDependencies.xml:12, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:33, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/OguryDependencies.xml:9, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/SmaatoDependencies.xml:9, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/StartAppDependencies.xml:9, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/UnityDependencies.xml:9, Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/VungleDependencies.xml:13
        }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal" // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies/ConsentMangerDependencies.xml:7
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
// Android Resolver Repos End
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
**APPLY_PLUGINS**

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:24
    implementation 'androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:23
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.2.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/VungleDependencies.xml:10
    implementation 'androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:20
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:34
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:19
    implementation 'com.adcolony:sdk:4.5.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:41
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1' // Assets/AppsFlyer/Editor/AppsFlyerDependencies.xml:10
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:30
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:28
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:[26.0.0, 27.2.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:10.2.1' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppLovinDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:adcolony:2.10.1.12@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AdColonyDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:amazon_ads:2.10.1.3' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AmazonAdsDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:applovin:2.10.1.14@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppLovinDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:appodeal:2.10.1.2' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:4
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:bidmachine:2.10.1.11@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:facebook:2.10.1.14@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/FacebookAudienceDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:ironsource:2.10.1.12@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/IronSourceDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:my_target:2.10.1.12@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:ogury:2.10.1.8' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/OguryDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:smaato:2.10.1.6' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/SmaatoDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:startapp:2.10.1.12' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/StartAppDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:unity_ads:2.10.1.10' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/UnityDependencies.xml:6 
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.networks:vungle:2.10.1.7@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/VungleDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk.services:crash_hunter:2.10.1.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:12
    implementation 'com.appodeal.ads.sdk:core:2.10.1@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.appodeal:protobuf-models:1.1.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:6.3.2' // Assets/AppsFlyer/Editor/AppsFlyerDependencies.xml:6
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:unity-wrapper:6.3.2' // Assets/AppsFlyer/Editor/AppsFlyerDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.criteo.publisher:criteo-publisher-sdk:4.4.0@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:27
    implementation 'com.explorestack:consent:1.0.3' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/ConsentManagerDependencies/ConsentMangerDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.explorestack:consent-models:1.0.2@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.explorestack:iab:0.9.4' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/AppodealDependencies.xml:11
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.0@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/FacebookAudienceDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.7' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:29
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.8.4@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:26
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/VungleDependencies.xml:8
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/IronSourceDependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/VungleDependencies.xml:9
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[10.2.1, 12.1.0[' // Assets/OneSignal/Editor/OneSignalDependencies.xml:5
    implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.7.2' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:36
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.1.5.1' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/IronSourceDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.my.target:mytarget-sdk:5.12.2@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/MyTargetDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson-runtime:1.3.0' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:33
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.12' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:29
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:28
    implementation 'com.squareup:tape:1.2.3' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:35
    implementation 'com.vungle:publisher-sdk-android:6.9.1' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/VungleDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'io.bidmachine:ads.networks.adcolony:1.7.4.9@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:39
    implementation 'io.bidmachine:ads.networks.criteo:1.7.4.9@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:25
    implementation 'io.bidmachine:ads.networks.facebook:1.7.4.7@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:21
    implementation 'io.bidmachine:ads.networks.my_target:1.7.4.6@aar' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:7
    implementation 'io.bidmachine:ads:1.7.4' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:43
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72' // Assets/Appodeal/Editor/NetworkConfigs/BidMachineDependencies.xml:32
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}

// Android Resolver Exclusions Start
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
}
// Android Resolver Exclusions End
android {
    compileSdkVersion **APIVERSION**
    buildToolsVersion '**BUILDTOOLS**'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion **MINSDKVERSION**
        targetSdkVersion **TARGETSDKVERSION**
        ndk {
            abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
        }
        versionCode **VERSIONCODE**
        versionName '**VERSIONNAME**'
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-unity.txt'**USER_PROGUARD**
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress = ['.ress', '.resource', '.obb'] + unityStreamingAssets.tokenize(', ')
        ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
    }**PACKAGING_OPTIONS**
}**REPOSITORIES**
**IL_CPP_BUILD_SETUP**
**SOURCE_BUILD_SETUP**
**EXTERNAL_SOURCES**
```

чего не хватает для работы никак не пойму

Comment: На самом устройстве установлены [Google Play сервисы](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)?

Comment: да, попробовал на утсройстве с сервисами все срабатывает нормально, но как же быть тогда с устройствами которые под санкциями и не имеют этих сервисов, например Huawei/Honor?

Comment: Прежде, чем использовать Play-сервисы, проверяйте в коде их доступность с помощью метода [isGooglePlayServicesAvailable](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)). Для Huawei есть аналогичные [Huawei Mobile Services](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms) и метод `isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы не падать с такой ошибкой, проверяйте [доступность](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)) сервисов Google Play перед тем, как их использовать:

```java
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
```

Аналогично для сервисов Huawei:

```java
HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance().isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(context);
```